# Alternative of mechanize for browser handling job?

Tags: python, selenium, browser, mechanize

I am Python coder, would like to know, if is there any thing better than mechanize for browser handling job (like : opening a url, login form, scrapping links from source code,maintain cookie,etc)
I am also using selenium, but I would like to know ,if is there any other option for my specified works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I personally have found [Twill](http://twill.idyll.org/) to be perfect for automated logins - it comes with tools for scanning pages and locating links and forms.